# How to compare an element to another element , that is inside a nested list? (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logic, out-of-memory

I am given a list which contains the name and score of some students in the form of another list.

**For eg: lis=[['barry',35],['larry',20],['cathy',10],['mathew',10]]**

I need to find the name/names of the student with the 2nd lowest scores. for the above input the answers will be : **cathey
Mathew**

i tried solving it by the following way. But there is no output . **Can anyone identify the fault in my code?**

```
x=int(input()) #total number of element
lis=[]         #list
pis=[]
for _ in range(x) :

    name = input()    
    score = float(input())
    lis.append([name,score]) #appending name and score to lis
    pis.append([score])       #appending only scores to pis
pis.sort()    #sorting pis
lis.sort()    #sorting lis

x=pis[1]      #finding the 2nd smallest score in pis

for i in lis:

    
    if ((i[1])) == x:  #comparing the second smallest number to every score in lis

        print (i[0])    #printing only  the name if the scores are same,(this step don't work)
```

Comment: "pis" is also a list of lists (unnecessarily). So "pis[1]" is a list.

Answer (score -1):

```
x=int(input()) 
lis = [] 
for _ in range(x):
    name = input()    
    score = float(input())
    lis.append([name,score])

#changing list into a dict for sorting the data by its value. 
lis = dict(lis)

#using lambda function inside sorted() for targeting the value in dictionary to be sorted.
sort_orders = sorted(lis.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

#used for loop here to only print first two key items of the dictionary sort_orders.
for i in range(2):
    print(sort_orders[i][0], end = " ")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will use it for the future post :)